# Как вынести расчет в отдельный метод?

Tags: java, алгоритм

У меня вопрос по алгоритму. Делаю линеаризацию. Я хочу загнать общую часть вычислений в отдельный метод. Чтобы не вдаваться в математические  подробности, приведу код и объясню.

```
 public ArrayList<Double> calculateCommonPart(){
    ArrayList <Ellipse2D.Double> transformedData = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Double> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i <pointList.size(); i++) {
        transformedData.add(pointList.get(i));
    }

    // линеаризация y = ax^b
    // считаем коэффициенты a и b
    double averageProductXY =0;
    double averageX =0;
    double averageY =0;
    double averageSqrX = 0;
    int n = pointList.size();

    double newX =0;
    double newY  =0;


    for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
        Ellipse2D.Double CurrentPoint = pointList.get(i);

        // разные newX и newY для разных формул, остальное общее для всех формул
        newX = Math.log(CurrentPoint.getX());
        newY = Math.log(CurrentPoint.getY());

        averageX += newX;
        averageY +=newY;
        averageSqrX += Math.pow(newX, 2);
        averageProductXY += newX*newY;

    }
    averageProductXY /=n;
    averageX/=n;
    averageY/=n;
    averageSqrX/=n;

    double sqrDispX = 0d;
    sqrDispX = averageSqrX - Math.pow(averageX,2);
    double a =(averageSqrX*averageY - averageX*averageProductXY)/sqrDispX;
    double b =0d;
    b = (averageProductXY-averageX*averageY)/(sqrDispX);

    result.add(a);
    result.add(b);
return result;
}
```

Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как реализовать вариативное присваивание переменным  `newX` и `newY` их значений. Например, для функции вида `y = ax^b`newX = Math.log(x); newY = log(y)`, а для функции`y = x/(ax+b)`newX = 1/x newY = 1/y`

Привожу таблицу линеаризации[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно эту разную часть разграничить с общей? Подскажите алгоритм

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализуйте патерн шаблонный метод

Помещаете ваш метод в Абстрактный класс

```
public abstract class CalculatorAbstract{

    public ArrayList<Double> calculateCommonPart(){
        ...

        // разные newX и newY для разных формул, остальное общее для всех формул
        newX = getNewX();
        newY = getNewY();
        ...

    } 

    public abstract double getNewX();
    public abstract double getNewY(); 

}
```

Дальше создаете конкретные реализации

```
public class CalculatorConcrete extends CalculatorAbstract{
    @Override
    public double getNewX(){
        return Math.log(CurrentPoint.getX());
    }

    @Override
    public double getNewY(){
        return Math.log(CurrentPoint.getY());
    } 
}
```

Подробней про паттерн можно прочитать здесь https://systems-ez.ru/index.php/ru/patterns/template-method

Answer (score 0):

Вынестие частное в отдельные классы, которые реализуют один и тот же интерфейс, и в общем коде обращайтесь к этому интерфейсу

```
interface newXY { // если x и y вычисляются всегда одинаково, то достаточно и одного метода
  double getNewX(double x);
  double getNewY(double y);
}

// и несколько реализаций по функциям

class newXYLog implements newXY {
  @Override
  double getNewX(double x) {
    return Math.log(x);
  }

  @Override
  double getNewY(double y) {
    return Math.log(y);
  }
} 

// и в коде у вас будет

newXY func = ...; //
...
    newX = func.getNewX(CurrentPoint.getX())
    newY = func.getNewY(CurrentPoint.getY())
```